# How to highlight code snippets inside of html file?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to highlight some code snippets(mainly java) inside of html document using python3. There are plenty of them in document. The code is tagged with pre-code tags. Can you advice me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the fragments highlight with [Pygments](http://pygments.org/)

You can use the [command line](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) directly or import the [lexers in your python code](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) if you want.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But how can I extract the fragments from HTML document?  I opened the document and read the content to string, but I don't know which function or method I can  use to get every occurrence of code between pre-code tags?

Comment: @Vladimir Then your question is not about highlight, but HTML parsing. For this you can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/)